# Any Fast & Efficient way to generate a 3D Grid?

Tags: c++, performance, computational-geometry

Is there a faster and more efficient way to generate a 3D Grid besides using the standard method which is going through 3 "`for()`" loops? I'm not using VTK, OpenGL, TetGen, CGAL, or any other complex libraries....just basic C++ software which is CodeBlocks. My code is shown below for the method:

```
#define Dimension 3
#define N_face 5000
struct Point{ float value[Dimension];};

struct Cube{ Point p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8;};

int main()
{
    Cube* Grid = (Cube*) malloc(N_face*sizeof(Cube));
    int m=0;
    /*......*/
    delta = ....
    for(int i=0; i<nx; ++i)
    {
        z = i*delta + ....
        for(int j=0; j<ny; ++j)
        {
            y = j*delta + ....
            for(int k=0; k<nz; ++k)
            {
                x = k*delta + ....
                Grid[m].p1= {{x,       y,       z}};
                Grid[m].p2= {{x+delta, y,       z}};
                Grid[m].p3= {{x,       y+delta, z}};
                Grid[m].p4= {{x+delta, y+delta, z}};
                Grid[m].p5= {{x,       y,       z+delta}};
                Grid[m].p6= {{x+delta, y,       z+delta}};
                Grid[m].p7= {{x,       y+delta, z+delta}};
                Grid[m].p8= {{x+delta, y+delta, z+delta}};
                m++;
            }
        }
    }
    /*......*/
}
```

In the code above, `x, y, z, delta` are floating values which are calculated to scale the grid size to a certain input geometry. I'm currently using this grid, to check for intersections (inside/outside) of grid points and polygon (referring to this algorithm of point inside/outside polygon [http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~pat/52233/slides/Geometry1x1.pdf ]) I've managed to complete the program and get the expected results but it's taking ages to run it as I'm dealing with thousands of points. Hence, now I'm trying to improve the coding.....really need your help....T.T

Comment: thousands ? maybe you mean billions rather ? because I have programs that does this kind of things on hundred of millions of points and it takes a few seconds. You can use `OpenMP` to parrallelize your loops easily here. Secondly, you can use fancy morton code iteration, it exists in 3D too. the goal would be to increase cache coherence but it would be a great implementation effort to get right for no prooven benefits. the best ROI is the `parallel for` here.

Comment: Ya, this is actually the 1st part of the coding project...whereby creating the serial code first then next part is parallelising it (my first time hearing this since then)....so gonna move on to that...many thanks

Comment: But if there's any other method in serial coding for this then do post some answers as well...would gladly learn more....^^

Comment: High level optimizations almost always blow away lower level optimizations. Since you haven't told us your end goal, there's no way to give you real advice. For example, you could create three groups of orthogonal line segments to represent a grid, check your intersections against those line segments, and ditch the individual points entirely; or maybe ditch the grid, and build grid points directly in the interior of the things you are intersecting with. Or marching cubes, etc. But we have no way of knowing if that's appropriate for you or not. Optimize your program *as a whole* first.

Comment: @JasonC I've already mentioned what i'm using this for as stated above....whereby using every grid points n check whether it's inside/outside a polygon...unless there's a better way to check for intersection between a Grid and an input polygon....like the one u mentioned....i'll research on tht...

Comment: @AmosChew You haven't told us your goal in doing that, and you certainly didn't read and comprehend my comment. E.g. the first two things I mentioned (line segments or computing grid points directly from polygon interiors) both still cover your description and represent orders of magnitude increased performance, but again, we have no way of knowing if that's appropriate or not.

Comment: @AmosChew Are all your polygons convex? Polygons are 2D, are they all aligned on axis planes? Also research octrees, which may or may not be useful for you.

Comment: @JasonC Sorry for not being detail.....my 3D input geometry is a complex one (has holes, convex)....i'm trying to design a shrink-wrapping program...hence, finding the intersections of grid with polygon and then projecting the vertex of grid onto the input polygon, creating a new layer with is close to the input geometry...

Comment: @JasonC after finding the intersections....I've used KDtree to project the outer vertex (just at the surface of the geometry) onto the input geometry (projecting onto nearest segment). I've done those but it's taking about 45secs to run it for a 1.5k points (input geometry).

Comment: @AmosChew If you are trying to find the closest grid points to the line segments that make up the edges of your polygons, you could approach from the other direction and instead of trying to *find* intersecting grid points, create the grid points directly from your line segments by "drawing" your line segments in a pixelated 3D grid. E.g. if you wanted to draw a line on a 2D grid (like on your screen) you would use e.g. the Bresenham or Wu line algorithm to directly determine 2D grid coords from endpoints, rather than testing *every* pixel on the screen to see if it is close to the line.

Comment: (This would greatly narrow your search set.) Or, within your existing algorithm, another simple optimization is to calculate the bounding box of your input polygons, expand it a bit for the "shrink wrap" range, and at the very least *only* iterate over grid points within that box (remember your grid is evenly spaced so you can index `Grid` elements directly and skip over ones outside the bounding box).

Comment: @JasonC Bounding box (u meant by the length, width, height of geometry)...n then my Grid size will be just within that box n the iterations (delta) is calculated then find the intersections from there?

Comment: @AmosChew Sure, consider that (with bounds checking of course) you can directly compute the index into `Grid` of the `Cube` that contains any arbitrary coordinate *(X,Y,Z)* by `int i = floor(X/delta), j = floor(Y/delta), k = floor(Z/delta); int index = k+j*nz+i*ny*nz;` and now `Grid[index]` is the `Cube` that contains that point. Use that to your advantage. You can also e.g. compute the bounding box of a polygon (min/max X Y and Z), then compute the grid indices for the bounding box edges, then you can do things like iterate only over the indices in `Grid` that correspond to that bounding box.

Comment: Too much to type in a comment but consider what I just said and think about it a bit and see if you get any inspiration.

Comment: @JasonC many thanks to u....i'll try to implement this bounding box method improving the serial coding part....i've gone through the octree algorithm and tried to implement but i couldnt understand part of it and hence failed to do it, but i'll try to make that work if i've extra time...

Comment: @v.oddou thank you as well....i'll try to improve this serial part first n see whether my supervisor gives the 'ok' answer to move onto the parallel coding...^^

Comment: you know in the code you gave "moving to parallel coding" is done in one line, and its not even code, its a pragma. that's basically smoothless. you have to think about details though, like variables must be absolutely calculated from indices and not from their provious values. http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/ check the first example, initializing a table in parallel, you can see the similarity with your thing.

Comment: I think you'd better ask another question about the intersection problem you are tackling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory allocation can be slow - don't do it unless you need to - and do as little of it as possible:

Your cubes contain a heap of information that could be computed at run time, and is almost the same from Cube to cube.  I'm assuming that there is extra information stored in each Cube, which I'm going to call `CubeMutableData`.

I'd consider doing something like this:

```
struct CubeMutableData {
  boolean inside;
};

struct Cube {
  Point p1; 
  ..
  CubeMutableData * data;
};

class CubeBuilder {
  //TODO: This needs an appropriate constructor that initializes these
  CubeMutableData * perCubeData;
  float delta;
  public:
  Cube createCube(int i, int j, int k) {
    Cube result;
    float z = i*delta + ....
    float y = j*delta + ....
    float x = k*delta + ....
    result.p1 = Point(x,y,z);
    result.p2 = Point(...);
    ..
    result.data = perCubeData[i+j*nx+k*nx*ny];
  }
}

int main() {

  CubeBuilder cubes(nx,ny,nz, delta, origin);

  // Loop through the cubes and use them.
  // Note that the Cubes geometry is transient, but their data
  // is saved back into the perCubeData member of the CubeBuilder.
  for(int i=0; i<nx; ++i) {
    for(int j=0; j<ny; ++j) {
      for(int k=0; k<nz; ++k) {
        Cube cube = cubes.getCube(i,j,k);
        Point p = cube.getCenter();
        cube.data->inside = geom.contains(p);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This allocates way less memory than your example, and the compiler should be able to optimize it pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if your code is already running slow for just a couple of thousand points, I would expect it to be a bug, even though I cannot immediately see any problems with your code...

About optimization:
There are two ways you can improve performance if you have to access a large number of elements: memory access optimization and parallelism.

The first one is to make sure that you always read/write memory in blocks instead of jumping around between distant addresses. This reduces the time lost by loading new pages into the cache.
However: in your example you already write to the memory sequentially by writing `Grid[m] = ...; m++;`, so this is already optimal.

The second way would be to use SIMD instructions: SSE allows you to write several float values at the same time and can thus speed up your process.

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>
...
__m128 your_first_four_floats  = _mm_set_ps (a, b, c, d);
__m128 your_second_four_floats = _mm_set_ps (e, f, g, h);
...
_mm_store_ps(((float*)&Grid[m])+0,your_first_four_floats);
_mm_store_ps(((float*)&Grid[m])+4,your_second_four_floats);
...
```

This is a very crappy example, so please don't take it seriously. You can find better ways to generate your values easily!
Also make sure that your allocated memory is 16byte aligned (should be the default in 64bit code, in 32bit code you need to use `_aligned_malloc(bytes, 16)`). Else you'll have to use `_mm_storeu_ps` which is a bit slower.

If you have a multi-core CPU (usually the standard these days) you can also use multiple threads to generate the values, but for that you need some threading library or a rather new version of C++ (C++11) which is not always supported. Also, this does not necessarily give you any speed-up if memory access is your bottle-neck.

Comment: This is good advice, but I would tend towards higher level optimizations, such as finding an algorithm that can directly determine an intersecting set of grid-aligned 3D points from input polygons without iterating over a huge 3D grid and testing each point. Like when you draw a line on the screen, you compute the 2D grid-aligned pixels from the endpoints, rather than testing every point on the screen to see if it's near the line. Then, with a better algorithm, optimizing a way to "test every point on the screen to see if it's near the line" becomes moot.

Comment: upvoted for noticing the already optimal access pattern, which puts my remark about morton code to nil.

Comment: @JasonC: the OP's code doesnt have a cubic complexity, even if it has 3 loops. this is linear in the problem space. he is just storing stuff. if we had a cubic complexity here the program would not even finish before the end of the next ice age. (I exaggerate but its for humour)

Comment: @v.oddou Sure! But significant improvements can be made by reducing it from linear wrt number of cells in grid to linear wrt number of cells that polygons occupy, or linear wrt surface area of the polygons. There are many improvements that can be made to the higher level algorithm, not the least of which is computing bounding boxes of polygons and testing just in those boxes. In my example with drawing lines on the screen, both testing every point and drawing line directly are linear complexity wrt *something*, but the latter is significantly faster.

Comment: @JasonC: You are right: it is always preferable to find a better solution to the (original) problem instead of optimizing the algorithm. However: the question was about generating (a 3D array of) values fast in C++, so my answer related to that. I encourage Amos Chew to try Jason C's approaches before trying to speed up the existing algorithm with SIMD/SSE or threading!

Comment: @Makx The moment when u posted your answer....i was like...woahh...i'm still way way far away from fully exploring the C++ world...i'll try on JasonC's method first...^^

Comment: @Makx Just to be clear so I don't come across wrong: Re: the specific question, this answer has excellent advice!

Comment: @AmosChew : don't hesitate to download VerySleepy and profile your program to see what comes at the top. One often finds that its easy to gain an order of magnitude of perf with a few trivial changes, when we know exactly what slows down the hole. Always remember the maxime, 20% of the code runs 80% of the time. Some people often say the truth is closer to 1%-99% :)

Answer (score 0):

The real issue is probably not with grid generation. Because you are using this grid for some purpose, and the processing time will dominate the time for grid node generation. So any micro-optimization there could be of no use.

This said, you are storing 24 values per node, when 3 are enough (X, Y, Z; Delta seems to be a constant). You can argue that it is faster to precompute the 8 points instead of recomputing them whenever you need them, but I wouldn't bet on that.

It is also possible that you needn't store the cube limits... at all !